# Python -- How to get Oldest date from a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet like this:

```
qs = [<book: OliverTwist_Mon Dec  9 00:00:00 2013>, <book: OliverTwist_Sun Sep 15 00:00:00 2013>, <book: OliverTwist_Wed May  1 00:00:00 2013>]
v_dict = qs.values('title', 'title__name').annotate(count=Count('book'))
```

I get this result from it:

```
[{'count': 3, 'title': 1, 'title__name': u'OliverTwist'}]
```

I want to include the oldest datetime in my dictionary,

```
[{'count': 3, 'title': 1, 'title__name': u'OliverTwist', rx_datetime: u'2013-05-01 00:00:00'}]
```

kindly help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate min datetime:

```
from django.db.models import Min
qs.values('title', 'title__name').annotate(count=Count('book'), min=Min('rx_datetime'))
```

It will give you something like:

```
[{'count': 3, 'title': 1, 'title__name': u'OliverTwist', 'min': datetime.datetime(2013,5,1,0,0,0)}]
```

Comment: What if I want to get the "PK" of book, by matching the 'title' and 'min', and place it too in v_dict?

Comment: I will use `filter` and `order_by` then slice the first, wondering if there is a better solution.